# Marriage certificate only shows maiden name

Tags: marriage, name, georgia

Before my husband and I got married, we filed for a marriage license at the court house, and it specifically had a line item for "name after marriage", in which I took my husband's last name. However, our marriage certificate we received only shows my maiden name.

Googling the steps to change a name after marriage, it's not entirely clear to me if this was a mistake (as in, the marriage certificate should show either my new name, or both names). Depending on which forum I read through, it seems like there is a mix of people who have their maiden name on their marriage certificate, their new name on the certificate, or both names.

Can anyone provide guidance? Is the maiden name on marriage certificate sufficient? This would be in Georgia, USA.